# Need for review the VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, locking, cell

I try to lock a cell base on another cell value. I used the codes some of you provided and worked perfect. I have some other codes with active sheet change too and VBA issue an error.
With the following code is working, but when the condition changed, I expect to the cell back to normal and be unlocked, but still locked.

The code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$B$7" Then
ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("mn")
If Target.Value = 10.4 Then Rows("21:26").EntireRow.Hidden = True
If Target.Value = 10.4 Then Rows("16").EntireRow.Hidden = True
If Target.Value <> 10.4 Then Rows("21:26").EntireRow.Hidden = False
If Target.Value <> 10.4 Then Rows("16").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
ActiveSheet.Protect ("mn")
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("mn")
If [E14] = "N/A" Then
[G14].Locked = True
'Remove locked property if E14's value is anything else or is deleted.
Else
[G14].Locked = False
'Optional, reprotect sheet
End If

If [E28] = "N/A" Then
[g28].Locked = True
'Remove locked property if E28's value is anything else or is deleted.
Else
[g28].Locked = False
'Optional, reprotect sheet
End If

If [E38] = "N/A" Then
[g38].Locked = True
'Remove locked property if E38's value is anything else or is deleted.
Else
[g38].Locked = False
'Optional, reprotect sheet
End If
ActiveSheet.Protect ("mn")
End Sub
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please post the code as text rather than as a link to a picture.

Comment: One of your procedures runs when a change is made. The other runs when the sheet is activated. Which one is giving you a problem?

Comment: Than you for reviewing, The 2nd part, When F14 is not equal "N/A", I expect the cell G14 be unlocked and I can enter the value. But, G14 still locked! (and the same for other cells.)

Comment: Does it only stay locked when you are **on** the sheet and change E14 (not F14) to `"N/A"`, because you are only unlocking it in the `Activate` event of the sheet. (So, if you leave the sheet and come back, does it unlock then?)

Comment: Hi, Yes stays locks even other cells are changed and no N/A in F14. If I need to put in `worksheet_change` , how can I do it without interrupt the 1st part?!

Comment: You keep writing F14 but your code is checking E14.  Which is it?

Comment: Yes, you right. My main cell is F14, but the E14 is the same and F14 gets its value if E14="N/A". I tried to change the cell may get fixed, but wouldn't,

Comment: But does your cell become unlocked if you leave the sheet and then come back?  (I'm trying to work out whether your `Activate` code isn't working, or whether you want to do a similar thing in the `Change` event to what you do in the `Activate` event.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is Your "N/A" given by a formula? because if it is you have to use

```
isError([F14])
```

And just a word instead of

```
If [E14] = "N/A" Then
    [G14].Locked = True
    'Remove locked property if E14's value is anything else or is deleted.
Else
    [G14].Locked = False
    'Optional, reprotect sheet
End If
```

you can Use

```
[G14].Locked = ([E14] = "N/A")
```

Comment: Yes, the value in E14 and F14 are from a formula.

Comment: `[G14].Locked = ([E14] = "N/A")` for True or False.

Comment: This code did worked perfect on another project but was on `worksheet_change`. I used another code with `worksheet_change` and VBA does not let the code to perform!